# Replicate Media Galley Edit view in Add Media View

Tags: uploads, media, media-library

I need little support of you guys with regards to one of the functionalities which are regarding the WP Media gallery, so, any help will be really helpful to me.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange! In order to get a specific answer to your question it's recommended that you provide more detail in your question. For example you could provide more information on which functionality of the Media Gallery you wish to change, you could provide code you have tried and even resources you have used. A visual representation of what you want to achieve could also be helpful. Providing more information helps people provide succinct answers. Ref: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please see the screenshot: I want below functionality http://prntscr.com/oam1d3 with new media upload as well. Basically, i have created 2 custom fields at the time of editiing any media from media galley which are required fields and i want to keep those as a required one when any image gets uploaded to media section. so any help with this?